# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient CommandText limit of 1046

Tags: .net, sql-server

While using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient I am seeing these two errors:

> The length of argument CommandText exceeds its limit of 1046

> Could not find stored procedure

*This question is being posted to find these messages in a web search.*

Answer (score 1):

If you see either of the above two error messages then you are probably setting or inheriting the `SqlCommand` `CommandType` of `StoredProcedure` where you do not expect it to be set or inherited.

The default is `CommandType.Text` – if you set it to `System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure` you will get the above two errors when you really wanted `CommandType.Text`.

```
 mySqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

vs.

```
 mySqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
```